# How can I build voice search for my app on Tizen smart tv similar to youtube?

Tags: voice-recognition, tizen-web-app, tizen-sdk

I am building a voice search feature for my OTT application. However I can't find any API that Tizen TV SDK exposes me to be able to listen to the user's voice from the magic remote. I tried a voice search on the Youtube app and it worked.

Please help me know how this voice search flow works!

(My app is building on Reactjs. On smart TV, users can only use the remote control to speak).

Thank all!

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search on [Tizen Web API reference](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/index.html), I found this APIs which seem to be similar to your needs - [VoiceControl API](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/tizen/voicecontrol.html). I am not sure how it works with the remote controller you've mentioned, but I think that checking this API could be a good place to start with.

Comment: Thank you.
However that API only supports implementing a list of commands and then listening if the user says the correct command then the TV will execute the function assigned to that statement. It is not Voice Recognition.
I have contacted samsung support team regarding this issue. They answered Voice Search API is private so I got the solution to have that api.